# Изучение Angular 1

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, html5, web-apps

Доброго времени суток!

Есть задача: создать некое web-приложение при помощи Angular 1. В этом приложении при помощи `$http` делается запрос к API. При получении результата в виде JSON парсим его при помощи `ng-repeat`.

```
<div id="someId" ng-click="pasteInfo()" ng-repeat="someId in someId">
        <img ng-src="{{someId.poster}}" alt="Film Poster">
        <span>{{someId.show_title}}</span>
        <span>{{someId.release_year}}</span>
        <span>{{someId.category}}</span>
    </div>
```

Вопрос заключается в том, что нужно при клике на постер открыть новую вкладку и вывести в ней полную информацию о выбранном объекте. Просьба подсказать в какую сторону копать. Как передавать данные между контролерами?

Comment: Передавай id в pasteInfo. А там уже делай то что тебе нужно.